# JavaScript trigger event inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, jquery-events

I am trying to repopulate a form with previously stored values, issue is that many of the select boxes are loaded dynamically with ajax and there are other functions bound to the change "event" that populate select boxes based on previous selection.

- My issue is that for some reason I can't get the `.trigger("change")`
  to work so my select boxes do not get populated and I have the code
  to bind `onchange` once a box is populated but cant get the first box
  to fire the changed event. If I enter `$("#mybox").trigger("change")`
  in browser console it works but not while inside js.

The values get set alright but event never gets triggered

`selectBox.val(this.selectedValue).prop('disabled', this.disabled).trigger("change");`

```
function repopulateForm(data){
     $(data).each(function () {
                switch (this.type) {
                    case "input":
                        $("#" + this.id).val(this.value).prop('disabled', this.disabled);
                        break;
                    case "checkbox":
                        $("#" + this.id).prop('checked', this.isCheckedBox).prop('disabled', this.disabled).trigger("change");
                        break;
                    case "select":
                        var selectBox = $("#" + this.id);
                        //Check if the select box has options
                        if (selectBox[0].length > 1) {/
        
                            if (this.disabled == false) //ignore disabled 
                                selectBox.val(this.selectedValue).prop('disabled', this.disabled).trigger("change");
                        }
                        else {
                            //Bind to element untill its filled
                            $(selectBox).one("change", this, function (event) {
                            data=event.data;
                                $("#" + data.id).val(data.selectedValue).prop('disabled', data.disabled).trigger("change");;
                            });
                            var test;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            });  
     };
```

This is how form looks initially:

[image: Initial State]

After I select a value the change event gets triggered and next box gets populated dynamically with options, and now it is enabled and has options. My issue is that I can't trigger the change event programmatically so next box can get populated.

[image: After Click]

Comment: Why are you using `$("#" + this.id)` instead of `$(this)`? jQuery can bind to DOM elements also. You don't need to always use a selector. Also, why are you setting `disabled` to the value of `this.disabled`?

Comment: `this` in my context is the element of the array that has stored values for each form element `$("#" + this.id)` is the same element on the dom that needs to be filled with the values from `this`.

Comment: Can you tell us how do you do to set a select value normally?

Comment: Some of the select boxes have functions bound to their change event those functions populate the select boxes below based on the selection. I just capture the values of all boxes at some point. Once the form is refreshed nothing is selected so i run my function to try to repopulate the boxes and restore the form state. When i select a value in the first select box i need to wait for its function to populate the next box and so on. I can set the value but i cant trigger the change event so the next box will have values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ook figured it out `.change()` works my issue was that i was calling it inside `$(document).ready()` but i was also binding there it turns out my change was getting called before the bind function all i had to do is call the change event in  `$(window).load()`

Answer (score 0):

The whole approach is a bit funky as i'm not sure what your trying to accomplish. That said however, binding should be done on an dom element that's a parent of dynamically added elements or higher still. For instance on the "document" object - that's because listeners are set when the dom is constructed the first time. So we have:

`$(myElement).on('event',function(e){ doSomethingHere});` - myElement will not trigger callback

vs

`$(document).on('event', 'myElement', function(e){ doSomethingHere })`. - myElement will trigger callback

First approach will not trigger callback and subsequent events bound to it. Second one will. I may be wrong, but i suspect that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just need the change event to trigger after i set the value for a select box element `$("#Myelement")val(this.selectedValue).prop('disabled', this.disabled).trigger("change");` will update the value and on it is visible but the change event never got triggered so the function that is boun to it never fires

Comment: I think .prop() does not return a jquery object, therefore you can't trigger an event like your're trying to do. Trigger it separately after.

Comment: I tried that makes no difference i tried running everything separate no change tried without prop same no difference. `$("#Myelement").val(this.selectedValue);` `$("#Myelement").trigger("change");`  value gets sent but change event never gets triggered.                                           My issue is that the event doesn't get triggered not the binding i have inside my loop.